# Is Indy for FreePascal stable?

Tags: delphi, indy, freepascal, indy10

I'm starting to play with FreePascal/Lazarus and there appears to be an Indy port available. Is this a recent port and is it stable enough to use in production use? (Standard HTTP post/get client type work, and basic TCPIP server side.)

Or, perhaps is Indy developed explicitly to be used in FreePascal as well as Delphi so the latest version will work?

Thanks!

Comment: I haven't used Indy with FPC, however from what I've read it's pretty stable, I would give it a go if I ware you

Comment: I've used it with the wst library (http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Web_Service_Toolkit) and had no problems.

Comment: yes, the latest version can be used in both Delphi and FreePascal equally.  Indy uses a multi-platform single-source codebase.

Comment: @Which is the latest version? The version I am using in FreePascal 10.2.0.3. Has it been superseded by a newer version? Is it on the indyproject.org website?

Comment: Indy 10.5.8(.x) is the current version number

Comment: Starting with Delphi XE4, 10.6 is the current version number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ive used Indy for a project, but just the basic client object.

Fetching a value from a server every hour, so nothing too demanding though

[CodeTyphon](http://www.pilotlogic.com/sitejoom/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=96&Itemid=148) saved myself any hassle of installing indy

Answer (score 0):

Afaik it works fine on the core platforms.  However versions from the unicode branch don't work designtime afaik.

Comment: Now that we're merged back in the trunk - is this still a problem?

Comment: Afaik yes. To my knowledge there are two problems. (1) the duplication of .inc files. I noted this on indycore several times, but nothing happened  (2) the designtime system of Lazarus changed, and Indy no longer works. But a new Lazarus is imminent, lets first wait till that is released

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is stable. The design components do not leak memory.  Some things like generic templates are not in Lazarus because it it not in FPC yet.